# Can I sort Rest by multple fields?

Tags: rest, client-object-model

How can I get order Reset results with 2 colums? 
`/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/News?$filter=Expires+ge+datetime'2012-11-23'&$orderby=Created`   also I want to order by the filed Topnews

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To sort by multiple fields, specify a comma-separated list of fields.

```
$orderby=Created,Modified
```

You can also specify `asc` and/or `desc`:

```
$orderby=Created asc,Modified desc
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385(v=office.15).aspx